# Data binding Int property to Enum in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

Below is a simplified example of a class I have:

```
public class ExampleClassDto 
{
     public int DriverTypeId
}
```

I also have an Enum that maps the Ids of DriverType to meaningful names:

```
public enum DriverType
{
    None,
    Driver1,
    Driver2,
    Driver3
}
```

But I want to bind this in XAML to a combobox. Unfortunately, because of the type mismatch, it doesn't like this. So in my ViewModel, I have to create a second property to map the two

```
public class ExampleViewModel
{
    private ExampleClassDto _selectedExampleClass;
    public ExampleClassDto SelectedExampleClass
    {
        get { return _selectedExampleClass; }
        set
        {
            _selectedExampleClass = value;
            SelectedDriverType = (DriverType)_selectedExampleClass.DriverTypeId;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedDeviceType");
        }
    }

public DriverType SelectedDriverType
{
    get
        {
            if (_selectedDeviceType != null) 
            { 
                return (DriverType)_selectedDeviceType.DriverTypeId;
            }
            return DriverType.None;
        }
        set
        {
            _selectedDeviceType.DriverTypeId = (int) value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedDriverType");
        }
}
}
```

Then I bind to the new property.

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource DriverTypeEnum}}" SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedDriverType, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

Now, this WORKS, but feels very gross. It's using SelectedDriverType as a converter. I want to avoid having to make the DTO's property a different type. Are there other, more elegant, solutions?

Thanks!

Comment: Can't DriverTypeId be of type DriverType?

Comment: It can, but that Dto is coming from a separate library that I can't change right now =\

Comment: So why not extend the existing class (`public partial class`) and create a property of type `DriverType` that get/sets `DriverTypeId` ?

Comment: @gleng: I think, in that case, I'd rather just keep the converter property. I am wondering if there's some other way to use SelectedValue or SelectedItem in XAML, or if a ValueConverter may come into play

Comment: @Killnine The other option is as you suggested, make an `IValueConverter` and just convert to/from the `Enum`.

Comment: I recall making a generic `IntToEnum` converter that I would make heavy use of. `ConverterParameter` was usually set to `{x:Type local:MyEnum}` to pass the enum type to it, and it would convert the bound int to/from that enum value. Might be worth investing a bit of time to make one for your common library.

Comment: @Rachel that sounds really useful, as this is only one of many enums I have in my solution. I'd prefer to make a more reusable solution for those. If you or anyone else can provide more solid example as an answer, I'll accept that.

Comment: I use a Dictionary<T, string>

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can have a generic converter say `EnumConverter` which will `convert int to Enum` to show it on XAML and `convert back from Enum to int` to set back in your ViewModel class.

It will work for any enum type. You just need to pass on type of enum in converter parameter.

```
public class EnumConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, 
                          System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        Enum enumValue = default(Enum);
        if (parameter is Type)
        {
            enumValue = (Enum)Enum.Parse((Type)parameter, value.ToString());
        }
        return enumValue;
     }

     public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, 
                               System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
     {
         int returnValue = 0;
         if (parameter is Type)
         {
             returnValue = (int)Enum.Parse((Type)parameter, value.ToString());
         }
         return returnValue;
     }
}
```

XAML usage :

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource DriverTypeEnum}}"
          SelectedValue="{Binding DriverTypeId,
                                Converter={StaticResource EnumConverter}, 
                                ConverterParameter={x:Type local:DriverType}}"/>
```

`local` is namespace where your DriverType is declared.

Comment: Awesome. That worked great. Just needed to add the following to my main resource dictionary to I could use EnumConverter as a resource: `<converter:EnumConverter xmlns:converter="clr-namespace:Some.Name.Space.Helpers" x:Key="EnumConverter"/>`. SUPER glad I can reuse this in my other ViewModels that use Enums. Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

The accepted answer requires you to specify the enum's type as a converter parameter on each binding.

If you are binding to an enum property, the converter can determine the enum type from the `targetType` property, which can be more ergonomic and less error prone.

```
public sealed class BidirectionalEnumAndNumberConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return null;

        if (targetType.IsEnum)
        {
            // convert int to enum
            return Enum.ToObject(targetType, value);
        }

        if (value.GetType().IsEnum)
        {
            // convert enum to int
            return System.Convert.ChangeType(
                value,
                Enum.GetUnderlyingType(value.GetType()));
        }

        return null;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // perform the same conversion in both directions
        return Convert(value, targetType, parameter, culture);
    }
}
```

This also works regardless of the underlying enum type (`int`, `short`, `byte`...).

When invoked, this converter flips the value's type between int/enum value based purely on the `value` and `targetType` values. There are no hard-coded enum types in the source, so it's quite reusable.

Comment: This does not appear to work for a combobox as selected value is object. The target type when receiving the int will be object and you will therefore not know what enum to convert to.

Comment: @aliceraunsbaek you're right, the binding target must provide the enum type for this approach to work. The accepted answer may be better in cases like yours.

Comment: I've addressed that issue by adding an optional `EnumType` property that, when set, would supersede the `targetType`.  Basically, the converter can operate in two different modes: static, where the enum type is explicitly set; or dynamic, where it's determined by the `Convert` parameters.

Comment: @MikeStrobel, It would be very helpful if you would share your revised approach and show all we need to do to use it.

Answer (score 3):

Storing an enum as an int is a bad idea in the first place. Anyway I would use a two-way proxy property instead of a separate class:

```
public int DriverTypeId { get; set; }

public DriverType IntAsEnum // proxy property, doesn't store any value, only does the conversion
{
    get { return (DriverType)DriverTypeId; }
    set { DriverTypeId = (int)value; }
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide more information why is it a bad idea?

Comment: See: primitive obsession